# Spinning in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

in my application when passing a activity to another waiting there a few seconds to load data, and I want to display a circular ProgressBar spins located in the ActionBar meantime.
I managed to place the ProgressBar in the ActionBar and starts to rotate by clicking on an icon of the ActionBar with this code:

```
if (item.getItemId () == R.id.MenuProgress) {
    item.setActionView (new ProgressBar (this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle));
    item.expandActionView ();
    return true;
}
```

but what I really want is to run to launch the new activity, ie invoke it from the method 'OnPreExecute ()' of AsyncTask that launches the new class.
How I can do? Anyone can help me.
Thank you.